# How to write multiple if conditions ladder in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting, I wish to have if condition ladder
I am reading a string, based on which I want the correct if condition to be processed.

**The logic is as follows -**

If the string contains a substring `-deploy`, only then allow it to enter the if condition ladder.

If the string contains both `-functions` and `-layer` substrings, then only my 1st if condition block needs to be called,

elsif check for `-functions` substring

elsif check for `-layer` substring

**I've come up with the following code so far-**

```
commitMessage='[STABLE] -deploy -functions [one,two] -layer some commit message'

if [[ ($commitMessage == *"deploy"* ) && ($commitMessage == *"functions"*) || ($commitMessage == *"layer"*) ]] ; then
  if [[ ($commitMessage == *"functions"*) && ($commitMessage == *"layer"*) ]] ; then
    echo 'functions and layer'
  fi

  elsif [[ $commitMessage == *"functions"* ]] ; then
    echo 'functions only'
  fi

  elsif [[ $commitMessage == *"layer"* ]] ; then
    echo 'layer only'
  fi
fi
```

**I am getting a syntax error for elsif -**

```
syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
```

**I am referring this, but don't understand what I'm doing wrong -**
[Bash IF : multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974788/bash-if-multiple-conditions)

Comment: The error says `elif`, but the code in your question uses `elsif` (with an **s**).  Are you using `elif` throughout?  Also, shellcheck.net may be able to point out the issue.

Comment: Assuming your original code says `elif` (as in your error message) then the main error is the `fi`s that you have before the `elif`s. Just remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the usage of incorrect `if` clause terminators inside the nested `if` clause and using incorrect keyword for else if branching i.e. `elif` instead of `elsif` (the latter is used in Python). See https://ideone.com/1sw0q5

But a `case` statement would be rather more readable in this case which could be written as

```
if [[ $commitMessage == *"-deploy"* ]]; then
     case "$commitMessage" in
         *"-functions"*"-layer"*) echo 'functions and layer' ;;
         *"-functions"*) echo 'functions only' ;;
         *"-layer"*) echo 'layer only' ;;
         *) echo 'no match'
     esac
fi
```

Comment: Thanks @Inian using switch was a much cleaner approach than the messy if else nesting for my case

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not be using `elsif`, instead you should be using `elif`.
You can refer the below documentation.
https://tecadmin.net/tutorial/bash-scripting/bash-if-else-statement/